# ¿Como generar un CheckBoxList en asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

espero me puedan apoyar, estoy tratando de mostrar una lista en mi vista en un CheckBoxList, pero me sale error a la hora de ya querer mostrarlo en mi vista.

En mi controlador realizo esto:

```
var modelo = new EmpleadoCreacionViewModel
        {
            TiposFacilities = await ObtenerFacilities()
        };

private async Task<IEnumerable<SelectListItem>> ObtenerFacilities()
    {
        var tipoFacilities = await repositorioFacilities.Obtener();
        return tipoFacilities.Select(facility => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = facility.Nombre,
            Value = facility.IdFacility.ToString()
        }).ToList();
    }
```

En mi repositorioFacilities tengo esto:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<FacilityModel>> Obtener()
    {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return await connection.QueryAsync<FacilityModel>("select IdFacility, Nombre from Facility");
    }
```

En mi modelo lo tengo de esta manera:

```
public class EmpleadoCreacionViewModel: EmpleadoModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TiposFacilities { get; set; }
}
```

Con todo eso funciona correctamente al traer toda la información de mi tabla de `Facility`, pero cuando lo quiero mostrar en mi vista me marca error, lo estoy tratando de plasmar de la siguiente forma:

```
<div class="form-control">
            @for(int i = 0; i < Model.TiposDepartamentos; i++)
            {
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.TiposFacilities[i].Value" />
                <input asp-for="TiposFacilities[i].Selected" />@Model.TiposFacilities[i].Text
            }
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
-El primer error que me sale, es que no puedo utilizar los operadores de tipo int con un `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.
El segundo me dice que no puedo utilizar `[]` en una expresión `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Me podrían apoyar en comentarme que estoy realizando mal, me ayudarian mucho.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Podrías agregar lo que genera/renderiza ese código del final, por favor?

Comment: Hola, ya modifiqué la pregunta y añadí los errores que me arrojan

Comment: Coloca también la primera línea del View, para ver el tipo de dato que es `Model`

Comment: En tu vista como tienes el `@model`

Comment: En la vista tengo @model EmpleadoCreacionViewModel

Comment: agrégale el `IEnumerable` antes de Nombre del model

Comment: Ya lo intente, pero cuando lo agrego, todo lo demas sale con error y me dice "IEnumerable<EmpleadoCreacionViewModel" no contiene una definicion para "TiposFacilities".

Comment: Muchas gracias @Yussef, tu respuesta me ayudo mucho y asi es como me salio bien, eres un crack. Me gustaria que volvieras a colocar tu respuestas para votar por la que me ayudo.

Comment: @Hectorepg me alegro, ahí dejé la respuesta y agregue un pequeño detalle sobre el tema de los `checkbox`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu `for` llama a `Model.TiposDepartamentos` cuando debería llamar a `Model.TiposFacilities`, luego los `IEnumerable` se recorren con `foreach`, no tienen índices para recorrerlos con `for`

```
@foreach(var tipo in Model.TiposFacilities)
{
     
}
```

---

Lo anterior soluciona el problema del `for`, pero para que sean `checkbos` necesitas pasar un `bool` y tú le estas pasando un `SelectListItem`

Puedes crear un `Dictionary` en su lugar

```
public class EmpleadoCreacionViewModel : EmpleadoModel
{
     public Dictionary<string,bool> TiposFacilities { get; set; }

}
```

```
@foreach(var tipo in Model.TiposFacilities)
{
      <input asp-for="@tipo.Value" type="checkbox" />@tipo.Key
}
```

Comment: Ok, perfecto!! solo tengo la duda, solo creo el directory en el modelo o tengo que adaptar el Dictionary en todos lados? y en la vista sigo utilizando con foreach?

Comment: @Hectorepg Sin mirar tu código y casi adivinando te diría que solo en `EmpleadoCreacionViewModel`, pero todo depende de cómo siga tu lógica hacia dentro, porque en algún punto esos valores debes guardarlos en la BD, y ahí no se cuál es tu modelo. Por otro lado, recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada. Saludos